# Rails mailer undefined method `encoding' for #<Hash:0x774b2d51>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I am trying to send email in Rails. 
The code is

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "from@example.com"

  def send_password_reset(player)
    Rails.logger.info "Password email"
    @player = player
    delivery_options = { 
         user_name: 'sites.smtp@mymail.com',
         password: 'password',
         address: 'smtpout.secureserver.net' 
    }
    mail(to: player.email,
         subject: "Recover your Password.", 
         body: "Password email",
         delivery_method_options: delivery_options)
  end
end
```

**Controller**

```
if player.valid?
  player.send_password_reset_token #(Line: 209)
  render json: {SENT: 'YES'}
else
  render json: {error: "Player does not exist."}, status: :not_found
end
```

**Model**

```
  def send_password_reset_token
    password_reset_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(nil, false)
    self.update_attribute(:password_reset_token, password_reset_token)
    UserMailer.send_password_reset(self).deliver #(line: 25)
  end
```

The logger says

```
Sent mail to ranasaani@gmail.com (25ms)

Completed   in 433ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `encoding' for #<Hash:0x774b2d51>):
app/models/player.rb:25:in `send_password_reset_token'
app/controllers/players_controller.rb:209:in `password_forgot'
```

But I am not receiving any email and here is not any method `encoding`. Then what is causing this error

Comment: are you sending some kind of attachments??

Comment: no, just simple email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have u setup your mailer.rb like this

> ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = { 
>    :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
>    :port => 587,
>    :domain => "your.domain.com",
>    :user_name => ENV['MY_GMAIL_USER_NAME'],
>    :password => ENV['MY_GMAIL_PASSWORD'], 
>    :authentication => "plain",
>    :enable_starttls_auto => true }

Comment: Aren't these equivalent?

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html, have looked over the syntax over here...

Comment: have u setup your `mailer.rb` like this `ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => "mail.google.com",
  :user_name            => ENV['MY_GMAIL_USER_NAME'],
  :password             => ENV['MY_GMAIL_PASSWORD'],
  :authentication       => "plain",
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}`

Comment: its surely a problem with your smtp configuration, you need to mention it in your mailer.rb file and then you might not be needing `delivery_method_options: delivery_options` in your `mail()` method

Comment: @amitkarsale thank you, it wokred. But after removing `:domain => "mail.google.com"` from settings